# Remove the Process ID of Current Command in Awk

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have this command which prints all the process IDs that contain a certain keyword in their command line:

`ps -ef | grep 'somekeyword' | awk '{print $2}'`

This command, however, returns a list of processes including the current command. Is there a way to remove the current command from the list?